# Website is not scroll on mobile devices

Tags: css, wordpress, jquery-mobile, mobile, responsive-design

My site not  scroll vertically at all on mobile.Its happening only on all mobile  mobile devices but when i have checked on responsive checker website its scrolled.Hopefully someone here can figure out where the problem is.I don't know how to solved problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably due to a JS error you are getting in the mobile browser. 
try removing the JS files just for testing.